# Connecting HeidiSql with my application in Java

Tags: java, heidisql

I have this applcation which I want to run, but it cannot connect to its database. It is written using jHipster,Angular and java.

I have this code to make the connection to the database:

```html
 <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
                    <url>jdbc:mysql://11.333.34.65:3306/some_name</url>
                    <defaultSchemaName>some_name</defaultSchemaName>
                    <username>hello</username>
                    <password>hello</password>
```

The application work prfectly in another PC, so it has no problems, but in my PC cannot connect to the database.
Now I downloaded HeidiSql as another option, and Heidi is actually connected to this database using the username and the pass provided above and hostIP.
Even though Heidi is connected to the database, my aplication has the same result.
I do this to execute the aplication :

```
yarn -clean install
yarn webpack:build
mvnw
```

And after some time the application appears in my localhost, but I cannot login that means that the database does not works. After this, I can´t see anyore the application, and in my cmd I see this error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73VJH.png)

I think that the only problem is with the database connection since I cannot login, and `AutoInmunidadMapper` exists in my app. Also the app works perfectly in other PC.
What should I modify to this code to connect now my application to Heidi, since Heidi is connected to teh database.

Comment: You need to show the stacktraces if you're getting errors connecting. Saying "it works here but not there" isn't nearly enough information.

Comment: @Kayaman I modified my qustion!

Comment: Well, looks to be an injection error. You need to find out why the bean isn't being found. Also check out the logs for stacktraces, that's where the important information is.

Comment: @Kayaman any idea on if I should modify the code above to connect with Heidi?

Comment: You're not showing any code. Instead of guessing you need to find the root of the problem. Since you're getting an exception from the backend (spring boot?) about not finding a bean you claim exists, that's where you should start. Find the logs and the stacktraces. Otherwise you'll just be blindly trying to find some magic button that fixes things. Find the error -> fix it -> repeat if necessary.